# erro ao tentar alterar um tabela adicionando uma nova coluna do tipo datetime no mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ALTER TABLE tb_coletas ADD dia DATETIME NOT NULL
```

gera o seguinte erro

```
Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column
```

não entendi o erro, até onde eu sei está tudo normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você criou uma coluna que é `NOT NULL`, ela tem que ter algum valor. Como você não indicou o valor *default*, é usado o ["*implicit default value*"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html), que no caso é o "zero".

Então você teria que colocar algum valor *default* para esta coluna. No caso, [você pode escolher a data atual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html):

```
ALTER TABLE tb_coletas ADD dia DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Ou algum valor fixo qualquer:

```
-- 21 de janeiro de 2020, às 10:30
ALTER TABLE tb_coletas ADD dia DATETIME NOT NULL default '2020-01-21 10:30:00';
```

---

Ou, se a data pode ser vazia, então retire o `NOT NULL`.